# How do I make my app fetch from local if there is no connectivity and from remote if there is?

Tags: android, rx-java2, android-room, android-architecture-components

My `MainRepository` is what fetches data from the API and inserts into the database, then displaying on the UI.

```
override fun fetchAll() {
    Observable.fromCallable { local.fetchPosts() }
        .doOnNext {
            remote.fetchPosts().concatMap { posts ->
                local.insert(*posts.toTypedArray())
                Observable.just(posts)
            }
        }
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(
            { outcome.success(it) },
            { error: Throwable -> outcome.failed(error) }
        ).addTo(compositeDisposable)
}
```

The `outcome` variable is a `PublishObject` of type `Response`, that is `Loading`, `Success`, or `Failure`.

```
override val outcome = PublishSubject.create<Response<List<Post>>>()

[...]

sealed class Response<T> {
    companion object {
        fun <T> loading(loading: Boolean): Response<T> = Progress(loading)
        fun <T> success(data: T): Response<T> = Success(data)
        fun <T> failure(e: Throwable): Response<T> = Failure(e)
    }

    data class Progress<T>(var loading: Boolean) : Response<T>()
    data class Success<T>(var data: T) : Response<T>()
    data class Failure<T>(var e: Throwable) : Response<T>()
}
```

It executes a method `local.fetchPosts()`, which is a function responsible to access DAO functions.

```
fun fetchPosts() = database.postDao().fetchAll()

[...]

@Query("SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY createdAt DESC")
fun fetchAll(): List<Post>
```

The `addTo` is an extension of `Disposable`:

```
fun Disposable.addTo(compositeDisposable: CompositeDisposable) {
    compositeDisposable.add(this)
}
```

I've tried using `concatMap` right after the `Observable.fromCallable`, but it will display data from the API directly while `doOnNext` will show from the database but it will not update the list, removing what has been removed from the remote server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to understand that `doOnNext` is a [Side Effect Operator](https://www.grokkingandroid.com/rxjavas-side-effect-methods/), along with it's family, side effect operators only anticipate the emiisions for doing a minor action (like logging for example), they don't affect the stream in anyway.

So, with that you're doing the observable

```
remote.fetchPosts().concatMap { posts ->
            local.insert(*posts.toTypedArray())
            Observable.just(posts)
        }
```

Never gets to work, because it's not being subscribed to.
Now you have to make a decision depending on the behavior you want, I'll assume that your use case is:

- Try to get data from API.
- if successful cache it, if not query DAO
- Display it

then something like this will work:

```
remote.fetchPosts()
    // cache the data from remote.
    .doOnNext(posts -> local.insert(*posts.toTypedArray()))
    // if an error happens, use the posts in the DAO.
    .onErrorResumeNext { Observable.fromCallable { local.fetchPosts() } }
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    [...]
```

Comment: The `onErrorResumeNext` has an error that says "overload resolution ambiguity. All these functions match". The `subscribe` also shows an error, on the `it`, saying its reference is unresolved. I omitted the rest of the code because I thought to be unnecessary, but apparently, it matters. I updated the question showing it entirely. I tried with `doOnError` instead, but it doesn't work.

Comment: The method to fetch local data seems not to work from within the `doOnError`, just if I call at the top.

Comment: I've fixed it now. The `onErrorResumeNext` needed `_: Throwable`.

Comment: Funny enough, it solves ANOTHER problem I was having, not the one described on the title of the question. I will rename it accordingly and open a new one, since the problem about cleaning the base remain.